# How can I limit number of messages to be consumed within subscription per minute

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have got 5 instances of .netcore application that listen messages from Azure Service Bus topic. All of them uses single subscription to consume messages.

Are there any ideas how can I limit message consuming by subscription, eg. 1 message by any instance of the app. per minute?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you're using the built-in message pump (message processor) or consume messages manually, each instance of your consumer controls the concurrency level.

- For message processor, you control that with the `ServiceBusProcessorOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls`. See an example [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample04_Processor.md).
- For manual receive operation, you'd need to write a custom logic. See an example of manual receive [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample01_HelloWorld.md).

Comment: In my case each application has it own message processor, so it is impossible to set concurrency calls = 1. Moreover if I move logic to reciver, it doesn't garantee me that each message from topic be read with a 1 minute delay.

Comment: I'm not entirely following the requirement as I don't know the scenario. If 5 subscribers listen to the same subscription that's a scale out. You scale out to process more messages. Scale in and set the concurrency to one with a delay in  between. You won't be using the built in processor as it's not designed for this use case. It would be a manual receive. Still the answer below is covers your scenario. Unless there's more you'd like to share.